# DynamoDB and TableNameOverride with prefix

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am testing DynamoDB tables and want to set up different table names for prod and dev environment using the prefix "dev_" for development.

I made this test to print the table name:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride;  

TableNameOverride tbl = new TableNameOverride("test").withTableNamePrefix("dev_");
System.out.println("name=" + tbl.getTableName() + "  prefix=" + tbl.getTableNamePrefix());
```

This prints: `name=null  prefix=dev_`
***How come the name here is null ?***

```
TableNameOverride tbl = new TableNameOverride("test");//.withTableNamePrefix("dev_");
System.out.println("name=" + tbl.getTableName() + "  prefix=" + tbl.getTableNamePrefix());
```

This prints: `name=test  prefix=null`

***How can I get the table name to be "dev_test" ?***

I want to use this later to get a "dev_" prefix for all tables in development mode like this:

```
DynamoDBTable annotation = (DynamoDBTable) myclass.getClass().getAnnotation(DynamoDBTable.class);  
TableNameOverride tbl = new TableNameOverride(annotation.tableName()).withTableNamePrefix("dev_");
```

Or is there another solution to separate between dev and prod tables?
I first thought of putting them in separate regions but not sure about this.

Could also use this:

```
mapper.save(ck, new DynamoDBMapperConfig(new TableNameOverride((isDev ? "dev_" : "") + annotation.tableName())));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`withTableNamePrefix` is a static method.  So this line is creating a new instance of `TableNameOverride` with the String "test", and then throwing that instance away by using it to call the static `withTableNamePrefix` method:

```
TableNameOverride tbl = new TableNameOverride("test").withTableNamePrefix("dev_");
```

To answer the deeper question of separating test from prod, I would recommend having 2 separate AWS Accounts entirely, one for dev and one for prod.  This is the only way you can:

- See billing separately
- Ensure you *never* leak data between prod and test systems
- Have high scaling on a dev table prevent you from scaling a prod table higher

Comment: Re: "I would recommend having 2 separate AWS Accounts entirely, one for dev and one for prod": I strongly agree, *but* it still might be a good idea to use "dev_" and "prod_" prefixes, so that for any manual actions (e.g. via the AWS Console) it's visually obvious which one you're operating on. (It's very easy for humans to lose track of which AWS account they're working in . . .)

Answer (score 10):

I've faced the same situation and struggled with myself a couple of days to get that working.

Just in case you're using DynamoDB + Spring here is what worked for me:

**POJO class:**

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "APP-ACCESSKEY")
public class AccessKey {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 36)
    private String accessToken;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 15)
    private String userName;

    private Date dateInsertion;


    public AccessKey() {

    // ... All POJO stuff
}
```

**Spring configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Amazon Credentials -->
    <bean id="tableNameOverride" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticMethod" value="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNamePrefix"/>
        <property name="arguments" value="DES-" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dynamoDBMapperConfig" class="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="tableNameOverride" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="BasicAWSCredentials" class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
         <constructor-arg index="0" value="${amazon.accessKey}" />
         <constructor-arg index="1" value="${amazon.secretKey}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="amazonDynamoDBClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="BasicAWSCredentials" />
        <property name="endpoint" value="http://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dynamoDBMapper" class="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="amazonDynamoDBClient" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="dynamoDBMapperConfig" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Explanation:**

Taking into account that my AccessKey object point to APP-ACCESSKEY table on AWS DynamodDB then it turns out that after running this, your application will start to point to DES-APP-ACCESSKEY.

Hope it helps someone who's facing a situation akin to it

Cheers

Comment: I used the same configuration but the `tableNameOverride` is null and `tableNamePrefix` has the name of the table and it gives the error : `{table} not annotated with @DynamoDBTable`

Comment: few issues, 1. assuming dynamodb:repositories base-package is used, we need to add dynamodb-mapper-config-ref=?? along with amazon-dynamodb-ref

Comment: @shivarajan I didn't get what the issue is. In order for you get advantage of having a flexible tableNamePrefix you need to have a reference to DynamoDBMapper class which requires both DynamoDBMapperConfig and AmazonDynamoDBClient references. That's how the SDK has been defined.

Answer (score 3):

Same as Paolo Almeidas solution, but with Spring-Boot annotations.
Just wanted to share it and maybe save someone time:

I have dynamodb tables for each namespace, e.g. **myApp-dev-UserTable**, myApp-prod-UserTable and I am using the EKS_NAMESPACE env variable, which in my case gets injected into the pods by kubernetes.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig;

@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages = "de.dynamodb")
public class DynamoDBConfig {

    @Value("${EKS_NAMESPACE}")
    String eksNamespace;

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                    "dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com", "eu-central-1"))
            .withCredentials(awsCredentials())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentials() {
        return WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.builder().build();
    }

    // Table Name override:

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride tableNameOverride() {
        return DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNamePrefix("myApp-" + eksNamespace + "-");
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig() {
        return DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder().withTableNameOverride(tableNameOverride()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    // Marked as primary bean to override default bean.
    @Primary
    public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper() {
        return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB(), dynamoDBMapperConfig());
    }
}
```

With a table like this:

```
@Data
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "UserTable")
public class User {

        @DynamoDBHashKey
        private String userId;

        @DynamoDBAttribute
        private String foo;

        @DynamoDBAttribute
        private String bar;
}
```