# Managing dev/staging/production on DynamoDB - Conflicting Approaches. Does using DynamoDB Mapper for use of one approach?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

This question was asked 2 years here: [Managing dev/staging/production on DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877136/managing-dev-staging-production-on-dynamodb?rq=1)
also here: [DynamoDB Staging/Production/Development versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372601/dynamodb-staging-production-development-versions)

The accepted answer was creating separate accounts, with consolidated billing.  There seems to be conflicted approaches.
For instance Peter Sankauskas in his comments suggested that is not the "standard way" anymore.

His suggestion was to use:
"Use tags and naming conventions to separate staging and production."

Does his solution still hold up when using the Java SDK DynamoDBMapper as the table names are implanted in the annotations?

Thanks.
(PS: I would have added a comment, but I don't have the reputation.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain how we do it in my company.

All of our DynamoDB  tables have a prefix (dev_TABLES / stage_TABLES / prod_TABLES)

We have a DBConstants.java file with two sets of final strings. One for the table names and one for a PREFIX + "_" + TABLE_NAME.

All Mapper files are getting the name of the table from DBConstans.ACTUAL_TABLE_NAME

We locally switch between them when debugging.

In Jenkins, our Gradle build knows to pick the correct prefix before compiling a dev/stage/prod jar.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Chen, I am trying to avoid making separate builds for different environments, but I think your solution has given me the insight i needed to realize its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDBMapper constructor takes DynamdbMapperConfig which can have a "TableNameOverride" property. This can be configured to override the annotated table name. See this answer for an idea on how to do this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25274713

DynamodbMapper APIs (query/scan etc) also take DynamodbMapperConfig objects. This can be used to override table name even in operation levels.

So, coming to your problem-
I think its better to have separate accounts for production and test. That's because if you manage to corrupt the data in production table due to bug in code, it will be hard to restore unless you have sound back up/restore mechanisms. If you want to still go in this route, you can configure table prefixes based on stage as per above example.